# SRSS count how many rows in group?

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

[image]

I want to find how many rows will contain by **DateOfInvestment** group(Blue color arrow), if it contain more than one then above heading row will show "Date**S**" of Investment, or if it is single row then "Date of Investment".

I used IIF(CountRow("DateOfInvestment")>1,"...","...") its shows error

Comment: Is DateOfInvestment also the name of the dataset you are trying to do the CountRow on? Trying to make sure you are aggregating the right thing.

Comment: GRP name "DateOfInvestmentGrp" and attribute name is "DateOfInvestment"

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of distinct values in the dataset of the field being grouped.

```
="Date of Investment" & IIF(CountDistinct(Fields!DateOfInvestment.Value, "DateOfInvestmentGrp") = 1, "", "s") & ":"
```